# Why is this not a poset after adding zero?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computer-science, divisibility, relations

**The problem**

Consider the following set for divisibility. {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 96}. If 0 is added, the divisibility relation set will no longer be  a poset. Please explain why

**My Work**
    From what I've been reading,  [Division by Zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero), I 've come to the conclusion that the divisibility relation on this set is not a poset because it is not reflexive because (0, 0) is not in the relation for divisibility for this relation. 
Would the correct justification be that nothing can be divided by zero? This is confusing to me because the definition for a divides b is, is there an integer k such that b = ak? For something like 0 divides 6, this obviously wouldn't be true, because there is no integer k to make 6 = 0(k) true. However for 0 divides 0, any integer k would make 0 = 0(k) true. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: It would strike me that it is definitely still a poset after $0$ is added; everything divides $0$ because $0=n\cdot 0$ for any integer $n$ - so $0$ is basically just a maximum element in the poset.

Comment: Under the most common definitions, $0$ *does* divide $0$, because there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $0=k0$ (indeed any integer can do).

Comment: @egreg, I disagree.  There is no consensus about whether or not $0|0$.  Evidently, the book the OP is using believes that it does not.

Comment: @vadim123 No consensus? I've never seen a book telling that $0$ does not divide $0$.

Comment: @vadim123 $0$ divides $0$. There is no requirement that $0/0$ to be defined for $0\mid 0$ to be true.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, this is exactly my comment above.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor).  My favorite #thy book, by George Andrews, has $0\nmid 0$.

Comment: @vadim123 I honestly can't imagine why that would be remotely a useful definition. For example, once you get to ideals, divisibility as a subset relationship is fairly powerful. Now, if you added $-2$ to the above set, it obviously ceases to be a poset (which shows why the ideal view of divisibility is "natural," in some sense.)

Comment: One way it's useful is if $a|b$, to be able to use the number $\frac{b}{a}$, without a footnote each time handling the case $a=b=0$.

Comment: @CarlMummert zero does not divide 2, in any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Joffan: what was I thinking? Thanks for the quick correction.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: in my area at least, we often take posets to just be reflexive and transitive (not necessarily antisymmetric - so really just a preorder) so $\{2,-2\}$ would be a poset under divisibility.

Comment: @CarlMummert A relation R on a set S is called a partial ordering or a partial order if it is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. That's all the book says for the definition of partial order

Comment: @committedandroider: thanks - that is the "non-strict" version. I think you have identified the issue, which is that (in your book) they may assume that 0 does not divide 0. That is not the same definition that you would see in many abstract algebra textbooks. The fact that different fields have slightly different definitions can be surprising at first, but you get used to it after a little time with more advanced mathematics.

Comment: @CarlMummert So a valid justification is just saying nothing divides zero?

Comment: The important point is that 0 does not divide 0 in your book, which means that the divisibility relation would not be reflexive when 0 is considered - but your definition of poset says the relation must be reflexive. @committedandroider

Comment: @vadim123 You'd need a footnote anyway in more general rings than $\mathbb Z$ as $a\mid b$ does not imply that a *unique* element $\frac ba$ exists. For example, in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ we have $2\mid 4$, but "$\frac 42$" could be $2$ or $5$.